# How can I make my page be able to "scroll" and move back to the original spot?

Tags: android

I have no idea how to google this, I've tried some keywords but nothing turned up.

What I want to do is if you have the page open on the app and want to move it up or down that you're able to move it a little to create interaction, but once you release it should snap back into the original spot.

I don't want to actually scroll but just give the user the feel of interaction, instead of it just being a static page.

What is this called and how can I find a tutorial about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for can be achieved using a [SwipeRefreshLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html). It will do the thing you want but is actually to be used when you want to refresh the contents.

> The SwipeRefreshLayout should be used whenever the user can refresh
>   the contents of a view via a vertical swipe gesture. The activity that
>   instantiates this view should add an OnRefreshListener to be notified
>   whenever the swipe to refresh gesture is completed. The
>   SwipeRefreshLayout will notify the listener each and every time the
>   gesture is completed again; the listener is responsible for correctly
>   determining when to actually initiate a refresh of its content. If the
>   listener determines there should not be a refresh, it must call
>   setRefreshing(false) to cancel any visual indication of a refresh. If
>   an activity wishes to show just the progress animation, it should call
>   setRefreshing(true). To disable the gesture and progress animation,
>   call setEnabled(false) on the view.
>
> This layout should be made the parent of the view that will be
>   refreshed as a result of the gesture and can only support one direct
>   child. This view will also be made the target of the gesture and will
>   be forced to match both the width and the height supplied in this
>   layout. The SwipeRefreshLayout does not provide accessibility events;
>   instead, a menu item must be provided to allow refresh of the content
>   wherever this gesture is used.